# What is the best development environment for writing Flash websites / games for a beginner

Tags: flash, web, adobe

What tools / environment is needed to write professionally looking flash websites (animation, interactivity - image drag /drop, etc.?

I am not experienced in flash so take that into acccount

It seems like the default environment [from Adobe is Macromedia Flash](http://www.adobe.com/products/flash.html) but its unclear if you need this or there are other recommended tools that may be simpler to use or less costly.

Someone suggested [that i work in swish](http://www.swishzone.com/index.php), which looks interesting, but its not clear if swish is all you need or if you need macromedia IDE as well.

I wanted to get feedback from this community on what is the "right" setup to build good looking functional flash websites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A great free option for developing Flash games is [FlashDevelop](http://www.flashdevelop.org/wikidocs/index.php?title=Main_Page). It is an IDE that works with Adobe's free Flex SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need something that generates a SWF file for you from flash code.(Actionscript and ...) the best workflow tool that you could work with easily is the Adobe's Flash product that you mentioned yourself.
but, there are some other Open-source packages that could create the SWF file for you and teh y are mainly as plug-ins for Eclipse. here you would use Flex plug-in for eclipse that generates swf files from Flex projects (that also you can use Adobe Flex environment to produce). you can see a list of them here:
[open source flash development](http://www.flashmagazine.com/news/detail/open_source_and_free_development_tools_for_flash/)

the product you mention seem to be a somehow cheaper version of Adobe product for someone who doesn't one to use an open source alternative.
IMHO the best way to work in Flash sphere is to use adobe's own Authoring tools like Flash or Flex. they are very straightforward and also generating swf content with open-source alternatives is not without some headaches. the downside is of course High price tag.

Answer (score 0):

Swish is completely standalone, you don't need Adobe Flash for it to create SWF files (= author websites).

While others recommended Flex, if you want to do animations heavily (and not just transitions and UI animations) it won't do any of that, so you'll still need either Flash or Swish. So for example any cartoon style vector animations, shape morphing, etc. See this thread: [Is it possible to create (good) flash animations in flash builder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2638818/is-it-possible-to-create-good-flash-animations-in-flash-builder)

It's really up to what kind of websites you're after, but unless you need the advanced multimedia capabilities of Flash, maybe you'd be better off learning HTML5, JavaScript, CSS and SVG.